# using click event arraylist index not incrementing c#

Tags: c#

count in initially 0.
array list contain 3 questions at 0 1 2 index.
using click event on button it shows only the 0 index value whenever i click on button.
i want that whenever i click on button array index incremented and show the next question.

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (count != 3)
    {
        lbl_question.Text = question_list[count].ToString();
        rdb_op1.Text = op1_list[count].ToString();
        rdb_op2.Text = op2_list[count].ToString();
        rdb_op3.Text = op3_list[count].ToString();
        rdb_op4.Text = op4_list[count].ToString();
        count = count + 1;
    }
```

Comment: Where do you declare `count` here?

Comment: You need to write more content, this doesn't look wrong.

Comment: because  i want only 3 questions from array list. that's why i m using count.

Comment: using database query which select 3 questions and add these questions into array list.

Comment: count is use to increment the array list index when i click on button

Comment: count is declare globally.

Comment: Set a breakpoint at all lines that modify count and run in the debugger.

Comment: can you share code where you declare `count`

Comment: thanks its work for me.when i declare count as a static variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare a static variable so that it doesn't reset when you load the page

```
public static int count { get; set; }
```

and then use it in your event

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (count != 3)
    {
        lbl_question.Text = question_list[count].ToString();
        rdb_op1.Text = op1_list[count].ToString();
        rdb_op2.Text = op2_list[count].ToString();
        rdb_op3.Text = op3_list[count].ToString();
        rdb_op4.Text = op4_list[count].ToString();
        count = count + 1;
        }
    else
    {
        count = 0;
    }
```

Comment: thanks its work for me.when i declare count as a static variable.